# TCP Dumpを30秒間で終了させたい

Tags: macos, bash, tcpdump

tcpdump -Ini en0  -w test1.pcap を実行、
30秒たったらtcpdumpを終了したいです。

以下に試行錯誤の様子を記載します。

```
#!/bin/bash -v
timeout 30 tcpdump -Ini en0  -w test1.pcap
```

というスクリプトを書いてみましたが、bashではtimeoutを使えないようです。
    -bash: timeout: command not found

```
#!/bin/bash -v
timeout 30 tcpdump -Ini en0  -w test1.pcap
sleep 30
exit
```

と書いてみましたが、30秒経ってもパケットキャプチャは終了しません。

Comment: brew install coreutils を実行すると、`gtimeout` という名前のコマンドがインストールされるかと思います。それが `timeout` コマンドです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
まさにやりたいことが実現できました。

    brew install coreutils

こちらをインストールした上で

    gtimeout 30 tcpdump -Ini en0  -w test1.pcap

で動作しました。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-W` オプションと `-G` オプションを併用します。

以下のように起動することで、ログローテーションは60秒間隔 (`-G60`), ローテーション1回のみで終了 (`-W1`) となります。このため、結果的に60秒間で `tcpdump` は終了します。

```
tcpdump -i eth0 -w moemoe.pcap -W1 -G60
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。
sudo tcpdump -Ini en0 -w moemoe.pcap -W1 -G60で無事動きました。
繰り返し5回測定するようにも改修できますね。

Comment: `-W` で `1` 以外を指定する場合は、`strftime` 形式でファイル名を与えてください。(例: `-w moemoe.%Y%m%d.%H%M%S.pcap`)

Answer (score 3):

`tcpdump` をバックグラウンドで動かし、30秒 `sleep` した後に `tcpdump` を `kill` するというのはどうでしょう。

```
#!/bin/bash -v
tcpdump -Ini en0 -w test1.pcap &
sleep 30
kill $!
```